# What is the optimum way of switching in 64 different available probabilities

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I'm building an audio recording app where the user can choose a background sound for his recording and a voice changer effect then plays the recorded sound according to selection.

The background sounds & voice changers are each in a different scrollable selectable `UICollectionView`. When the user chooses a background voice or a voice changer effect i save their `indexPath.row` in a tuple this way `var effect = (0,0)`

Because i have 8 different background sounds & 8 different voice changers so the probabilities are 8 x 8 = 64 cases so added them to a switch case using this tuple but of course the switch case is so large.

I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of solving this case.

```
switch effect {
            //NO BG ONLY EFFECTS
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 0):
             print(" NO BG & none")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 1):
            print(" NO BG & robot")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 2):
            print(" NO BG & monkey")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 3):
            print(" NO BG & bee")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 4):
            print(" NO BG & elephant")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 5):
            print(" NO BG & mask")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 6):
            print(" NO BG & ghost")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 0 && effect == 7):
            print(" NO BG & speed")

            //BG WIND & EFFECT CHANGED
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 0):
            print("wind & none")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 1):
            print("wind & robot")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 2):
            print("wind & monkey")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 3):
            print("wind & bee")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 4):
            print("wind & elephant")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 5):
            print("wind & mask")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 6):
            print("wind & ghost")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 1 && effect == 7):
            print("wind & speed")

            //BG CITY & EFFECT CHANGED
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 0):
            print("city & none")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 1):
            print("city & robot")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 2):
            print("city & monkey")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 3):
            print("city & bee")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 4):
            print("city & elephant")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 5):
            print("city & mask")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 6):
            print("city & ghost")
        case let (bg,effect) where (bg == 2 && effect == 7):
            print("city & speed")

           // AND THE LIST CONTINUES...
```

Comment: Does a given effect behave differently depending on if there is a background sound or not? In other words, can you switch on background and effect separately?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist no the background only plays another instance of the AudioPlayer class using ready made audio files saved in the app the voice changer effect is the one adding effects to the recorded audio file using AVAudioPlayerNode class.

Comment: Why exactly do you need such a large switch? Do you have to do something specifically different for each and every case (i.e. the code cannot be generalized, because if it can then there is most likely a better solution available)? With only seeing the code above I'm wondering why a dictionary cannot be used. Hopefully i've understood the question correctly

Comment: @TNguyen because i don't need to reserve a dictionary in my memory for only two Int type items. One for the background sound and the other for the voice changer. So a tuple is the best solution i my point of view. Every case is different yes because each background sound is playing a different saved audio file and each voice changer effect is adding a different effect to the recorded audio.

Comment: @KeghamK. I don't really work with audio in iOS but can't you just store a dictionary where the key is the an `int` (where in your case bg == 1 is wind) and the value is a string that is the corresponding string name of the audio file? ( i'm assuming you load the audio / bg sound with a string name of the file name )

Comment: @TNguyen ok i understand your point but the switch is mainly to determine which background sound the user selected from the collection view and which voice effect did the user select from the other collection view using these two criteria i can choose which file to play and which effect to add to the recorded file. And play both files together.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the possible values with their adapted values (in your example, it seems to be words), in a static way if possible, then you can call the adapt operation.

e.g., with arrays

```
# pseudo-code
BG_REG = [ "wind", "city", "foo", "bar", "baz", "42", "84", "1337" ]
EFFECT_REG = [ "none", "robot", "monkey", ... ]
(...)
print(BG_REG[bg] + " & " + EFFECT_REG[effect])
```

The adapted values can be anything else (e.g. callback/lambda func...)